# Как создать кнопку поделиться в node telegram bot api

Tags: node.js, telegram-bot, telegram, бот

Подскажите пожалуйста как создать простейшую кнопку поделиться. Видел в некоторых ботах.

Кнопка под сообщением от бота. При нажатии на неё открывается окно выбора чата в который мы хотим переслать данное сообщение.

Гуглил 2 дня. Уже голова болит. Не могу понять как реализовать такую простую вещь.

Answer (score 0):

Обьявление кнопки

```
var But_Reflink = {
reply_markup: JSON.stringify({
inline_keyboard: [
    [{ text: 'Поделится ботом', switch_inline_query: 'https://t.me/name_bot?start=MTE0Mjg3NTU1Ng=='}]
]
```